# Erro de retorno no AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax, request

Pessoal estou com um problema de retorno no Ajax, tenho um botão que retorna dados html por AJAX, quando utilizo na página inicial (home) ou em categorias neste modelo http://www.site.com/diretorio os dados da requisição voltam corretamente quando solicito pelo botão que chama o AJAX mas quando estou em endereços assim http://www.site.com/diretorio/subdiretorio/subdiretorio2, a requisição por Ajax é realizada mas volta o html da home do site. A requisição vai na página para ir com os dados mas a resposta de retorno não é o html com os dados mas o html da home e só acontece quando estou neste endereço fazendo a requisição , nos outros dois endereços de estrutura funciona perfeitamente . Aguardo ajuda

Comment: Acredito que esteja utilizando URL relativa, pelo o que descreveu. Já olhou nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do navegador para certificar-se que a requisição AJAX está correta?

Comment: Como você não postou o código do JavaScript, irei recomendar que você utilize a URL completa ao informá-la durante a requisição, por exemplo: `/recebe_dados.php` ou `//www.site.com/recebe_dados.php`

Comment: Já utilizei URL completa no Ajax e nada , o Ajax retorna Erro somente neste modo de URL http://www.site.com/diretorio/subdiretorio/subdiretorio2, existe alguma ferramenta para observar este retorno porque quando estou neste modo de url a Ajax retorna a home do site e não os dados trabalhados em recebe_dados.php

Comment: @Casima Pressione F12 e navegue até a aba *Network* para checar as requisições.